# How to substitute curly brackets with round brackets in a grid of list

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, grid-layouts

I want to produce a table (or a grid) from my list of data, as follows:

```
eq01={0.01,1.02};
ev01={{1,3},{2,4}};
ev02={{5,5},{6,1}};
 data1 = {{"", "Equilibrium points", "Eigenvalues", 
   "Eigenvectors"}, {"A = 0",eq01,ev01,ev02}};

Grid[data1, Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text"]
```

And what I obtain is the following:

[image]

Is there a way to: 
1) flatten the lists under "Eigenvalues" and "Eigenvectors" without using flatten for every definition of list in the beginning? Because I have many eigenvalues and eigenvectors and it would be very long; 
2) substitute the curly brackets with round brackets, to have for example, in the second column and second row, (0.01,1.02)?

I hope the question is clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**
this works exactly as OP asked in the comments below
also for many rows

```
eq01={0.01,1.02};
ev01={{1,3},{2,4}};
ev02={{5,5},{6,1}};
data1=StringReplace[#,{"{{"->"(","}}"->")","{"->"(","}"->")"}]&/@
ToString/@#&/@{{"","Equilibrium points","Eigenvalues","Eigenvectors"},{"A = 0",eq01,ev01,ev02}};

Grid[data1,Alignment->Left,Spacings->{2,1},Frame->All,ItemStyle->"Text"]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, actually I did not mention clearly that in the eigenvalues and eigenvectors columns I would like to have: (1,3),(2,4) and (5,5),(6,1), so I would need to keep the internal brackets and substitute them with round brackets. Do you know how I could do? And is there a way to write the rule only once for the entire data (which is longer than just this one in reality) and not for every row? Thanks!

Comment: Esperanta, you said  "flatten the lists under "Eigenvalues" and "Eigenvectors"... but now you are changing both of your questions... let me see what I can do. You should also try yourself now that I showed you the basics ;-)

Comment: @Esperanta I updated the answer. Please check it

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use a custom formatting utility of some sort:

```
vectorForm[v_?VectorQ] := Row[{"(", Row[v, ","], ")"}];

Grid[data1 /. {
   m_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &) :> Row[vectorForm /@ m, ","], 
   v_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &) :> vectorForm[v]},
 Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One distinct advantage of this approach is that it leverages *Mathematica's* expression formatting capabilities and avoids the lack of robustness of `ToString[]`.  Compare the above method with @J42161217's on normalized eigenvectors:

```
eq01 = {0.01, 1.02};
ev01 = {{1, 3}, {2, 4}};
ev02 = Normalize /@ {{5, 5}, {6, 1}};

(* @MichaelE2 *)
data2 = {{"", "Equilibrium points", "Eigenvalues", 
    "Eigenvectors"}, {"A = 0", eq01, ev01, ev02}};
Grid[data2 /. {
   m_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &) :> Row[vectorForm /@ m, ","], 
   v_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &) :> vectorForm[v]},
 Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* @J42161217 *)
data2 = StringReplace[#, {"{{" -> "(", "}}" -> ")", "{" -> "(", 
        "}" -> ")"}] & /@ ToString /@ # & /@ {{"", 
     "Equilibrium points", "Eigenvalues", "Eigenvectors"}, {"A = 0", 
     eq01, ev01, ev02}};
Grid[data2, Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text"]
```

[image]

Something similar happens with ordinary fractions and square roots.

---

Original formatting, in which a set appears in set notation:

```
Grid[data1 /. v_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &) :> vectorForm[v], 
 Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think in order to get what OP asks you should replace `"{("->"("`

Comment: @J42161217 Maybe so.  I'm not sure, but the OP will clarify, I suppose.

Comment: OP clarified in the comments of my answer. I think you should check it

Comment: @J42161217 I had read that. I'm still not sure, since the OP did not say that the outer braces were unwanted. For all I know it's only the interior formatting that matters.  Currently my answer shows the set of eigenvectors in standard notation, which may or may not be a more desirable format. It's easy to change. As I said, you may be right, but it's the OP I want to hear from before I change the answer.

Comment: Esperanta explained that by "flatten" means "to keep the internal brackets". In your answer nothing has changed in terms of "flattening". Also all brackets should change to round brackets

Comment: Yes actually I needed to keep only the internal brackets and make them round. The answer by J42161217 is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Esperanta I'm glad I helped!

Comment: @J42161217 I don't know what you mean by the second-to-last comment, but the OP confirmed your interpretation, which is what I was waiting for.  You might want to address the issue your solution faces in some cases that might well arise in ODE systems, which seems like what the OP is dealing with.

Comment: @Esperanta Thank you very much for the clarification.  I've made the changes to meet your goals.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to define a form that automatically formats numeric vectors and numeric matrices as desired:

```
MakeBoxes[EigenForm[e_], StandardForm] ^:= Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {MakeBoxes},
    MakeBoxes[m_List?numericVectorQ, StandardForm] := RowBox[
        {"(", MakeBoxes[Row[m, ","], StandardForm], ")"}
    ];
    MakeBoxes[m_List?numericMatrixQ, StandardForm] := RowBox[
        BoxForm`AddCommas @ BoxForm`ListMakeBoxes[m, StandardForm]
    ];
    MakeBoxes[e, StandardForm]
]

SetAttributes[{numericMatrixQ, numericVectorQ}, HoldAll];

numericMatrixQ[e_]:=MatrixQ[Unevaluated[e], System`Dump`HeldNumericQ]
numericVectorQ[e_]:=VectorQ[Unevaluated[e], System`Dump`HeldNumericQ]
```

Michael's example:

```
eq01 = {0.01,1.02};
ev01 = {{1,3},{2,4}};
ev02 = Normalize/@{{5,5},{6,1}};

data2={{"","Equilibrium points","Eigenvalues","Eigenvectors"},{"A = 0",eq01,ev01,ev02}};
Grid[
    data2,
    Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, ItemStyle -> "Text"
] //EigenForm
```

> [image]